# Unknown contacts appeared out of thin air

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, contacts

My contact list op my iPhone 5s suddenly shows hundreds of contacts for people that I do not know with full contact info. I have synced with Facebook and have LinkedIn and Exchange installed, but these contacts are not part of my "friends". Has anyone experienced the same issue? What can I do?

Comment: Look if any of your accounts are hacked, by changing the passwords on them.

Comment: Do they show up in your [iCloud Contacts](https://www.icloud.com/#contacts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that Outlook had synchronized thousands of contacts from MS CRM. Deleting them from Outlook solved the problem.

Comment: A similar thing happened to me when I tried to read work e-mail (Lotus Notes) on IOS.  IOS, without asking, imported the entire worldwide address book of my employer—more than eight thousand people.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibility:

1: Facebook sync with your contact info, as I know, Facebook will suggest people you may know to you.

2: Are you using a same Apple ID with your families or friends? Contacts will sync to your other device with same Apple ID.

3: Are you using other's SIM card? SIM card store contact inside the micro chip!!

4: Your Apple ID have been hacked.....change your password immediately and never tell others your ID and password.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deselct contacts under the facebook app in settings, then select 'dont allow changes' under settings and restrictions.

Answer (score -1):

For me it seemed to be Outlook contacts.

[image].

I checked the group settings in Contacts as you see in the picture and all the junk contacts went away.

Comment: Can you clarify on how checking the group settings caused the junk contacts to no longer be present. Are you saying that you unchecked an option visible in the screenshot?